# The 'should be closed' description in the flag dialog is missing a word

Tags: bug, discussion, status-completed, meta, stackapps

[image: Flag Dialog]

The 'should be closed...' reason has this description (emphasis mine):

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not **about Stack Exchange API**, app, or script as described in the [help center](/help), and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

`about Stack Exchange API` isn't right.

I think it should be `about the Stack Exchange API`.

Should we change it to (changes in **bold**)? :

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about **the** Stack Exchange API, **an** app or **a** script as described in the [help center](/help), and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many things on the Stack Exchange network, some bugs resolve themselves within 6 to 8 ... years in this case.

The dialog today looks like this:

[image: close daialog with needs improvement as option]

> **needs improvement**
>
> - This question [needs updates](https://stackapps.com/help/closed-questions) from the author in order to be answered well or belongs on another Stack Exchange site.

As you can see the wording changed quite a bit.

I hope this qualifies as an improvement and doesn't have grammar or spelling issues.